# Getting Variables From Settings Screen In Main ViewController

Tags: objective-c, xcode, variables

I'm working with my first grasping of a settings screen. I set a boolean or something like that from within the settings screen which then would change something in the main viewcontroller.

For example, "Enable Private Browsing?"
^ Declared within the settings viewcontroller, returns a "YES" or "NO" boolean.

And if it returns yes, it would be enabled within the main viewcontroller. However, I need to know how it's possible to obtain that boolean in the main viewcontroller to actually enable/disable it using the value set in the settings viewcontroller.

Thanks for your time, and I greatly appreciate it.
-Jake

Comment: search SO for NSUserDefaults or read apples documentation on it.  I think that is a good fit for what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use NSUserDefaults

save on settings viewcontroller with:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"somecustomsetting" forKey:@"enablePrivateBrowsing"];
```

retrieve on mainviewcontroller with:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"enablePrivateBrowsing"];
```

this will be persistant(will be saved even after the app is closed) so remember to do
    on your settings view controller

```
if( [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"enablePrivateBrowsing"]){
privatebrowsingswitch.on = NO;
}else{
    if([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"enablePrivateBrowsing"] isEqualToString:@"somecustomsetting"]){
    privatebrowsingswitch.on = YES;
        }else{
       privatebrowsingswitch.on = NO;
             }
```

}

Comment: I should've guess NSDefaults, don't know why I didn't think of it. Thanks!